# How to check the type filter in file open dialog?

Tags: finder, high-sierra, mojave, filesystem, dialog

In windows, we can check the type filter easily:
[image]

But in MacOS, it seems the file open dialog has no such thing:
[image]

The reason why I want to check it: sometimes the `open` button is unclickable, but I don't know the file type it is looking for.

Comment: The open dialog doesn't have that particular feature, it just won't allow you to select types that it doesn't accept (type identifiers that are acceptable are pretty much up to the application developer).

Comment: @red_menace I understand that acceptable type identifiers are up to the application developer. It is just that windows file open dialog displays the acceptable type identifiers while macos file open dialog does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The granddaddy of macOS modifications [DefaultFolderX](https://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) that has been around since "classic" Mac OS does not even offer this option. Making me think that is not something that is available.

And after 20+ years working on Macs I have not seen anything like that I would generally think that there is no mechanism available to end-users that allows you to do this.

It *may* be possible to add certain apps to the database of programs that can open a particular file but that is usually done by an App when it is installed.

I would say that you are likely out of luck in situations like this.

However I have been known to drag 'n drop a file onto a program icon that will open pretty much any file (I'm lookin' at you BBEdit) and that, I have found, is a useful workaround, at least for me.

Comment: I'm out of luck. Maybe it is impossible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

macOS does have this ability, just not in the Open... window.

Right-click on a document > select Open With, then slide down to Other...

[image]

This opens a window to the Applications folder showing Recommended Applications that should be able (but not guaranteed) open the document in question:

[image]

You can then choose to select All of the applications in the Applications folder:

[image]

You can they attempt to open a file with any of the available applications in the Applications folder, and you can additionally navigate to other folders which may have applications available.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the answer. It is not that I have a file to open, but that a dialog wants to open a file. All file items are grey, which means they are not acceptable by this dialog. However, because macOS dialog does not show the acceptable type identifiers to me, I don't know the file type it looks for.